# What's the difference between returning with a coroutine and resuming a coroutine from await_suspend?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

The standard offers multiple ways to implement `await_suspend` in an awaitable type.
One way is returning with a coroutine handle to be resumed:

```
std::coroutine_handle<> await_resume(std::coroutine_handle<>)
{
    return otherCoro;
}
```

After the function returns, `otherCoro` will be resumed after this call, when its resume call returns, the original call/resume returns. Apparently the same effect can also be achieved with:

```
void await_resume(std::coroutine_handle<>)
{
    otherCoro.resume();
}
```

In this case the coroutine is explicitly resumed, then await_resume returns with void, so the original caller/resumer will return after that just like in the first case. In this approach the resume can be made conditional, while in the first case one need to use tricks, such as returning with `std::noop_coroutine()`.

Other than these cases is there any difference between the two approaches? Is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: The first version avoids stack overflow when the `co_await` appears in a loop.

Comment: See https://lewissbaker.github.io/2020/05/11/understanding_symmetric_transfer

Comment: Could there be a difference in terms of copy/move? The second approach might have less overhead for big coroutine_handle objects.

Comment: @battlmonstr `coroutine_handle` must be interconvertible with `void*` and must have a trivial destructor. This basically means that it is just a fancy name for `void*`.